# how to send post type request without parameter

Tags: jquery

[image]I am facing problem to send **post request without** parameter but i don't why it give  error ?

```
var url = SCRIPT_PATH + "?action=func",
$.post(url, function(response) {
  if (response.success) {
  }
}, 'json');
```

Before that when I want to send data I wrote this and worked perfectly fine:

```
var url = SCRIPT_PATH + "?action=func",
data = $('#sidebarForm').serializeArray();
data.push({
  name: 'isMobileDevice', 
  value: this.isMobileDevice
});

data.push({
  name: 'isNavTopFilter',
  value: isNavTopFilter
});

$.post(url, data, function(response) {
  if (response.success) {
}, 'json');
```

Comment: What is the issue? Both your usages of `$.post` are valid and should work fine

Comment: $.post(url, function(response){
            if(response.success){

              }
}, 'json')

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan syntax Error  in 1

Comment: Are you sure that's the line causing the problem? There are no syntax issues in what you've shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only declared one variable at the top, and then separated to the next command with `,`, which should be a `;`. It's a small syntax error:

```
var url = SCRIPT_PATH + "?action=func", // <-- here
$.post(url, function(response) {
  if (response.success) {
  }
}, 'json');
```

Fixed:

```
var url = SCRIPT_PATH + "?action=func";
$.post(url, function(response) {
  if (response.success) {
  }
}, 'json');
```